# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array related with 'can't read null array'

Tags: java, android, directory

I get a "Unfortunately 'App Name' has stopped" message from the emulator. I think the script can't locate the folder or can't read the file name. The photo of the res folder is attached. I tried things like *"res/drawable"* or *"/res/drawable/"* etc but I got the same result. 
I used the below permission in the manifest file but to no avail.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I checked all stackoverflaw related links but could not solve my problem.

```
package chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by serhat on 04.11.2015.
 */
public class klasor {
    private String drawable;
    private ArrayList<File> files;

    public void listf(String drawable, ArrayList<File> files) {
        File directory;
        directory = new File(drawable);

        // get all the files from a directory
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : fList) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                files.add(file);
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                listf(file.getAbsolutePath(), files);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My main activity file pls pay special attention to the path I gave for the files

```
package chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.satranc_tahtasi);

        File folder = new File("D:/Android_Dosyalar/Proje/PGNViewer/app/src/main/res/drawable");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
            if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
            } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the logcat

```
11-05 22:29:41.577 2215-2215/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-05 22:29:41.678 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime: Process: chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer, PID: 2215
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime:     at chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
11-05 22:29:41.679 2215-2215/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the path you're trying to access, change this

```
File folder = new File("D:/Android_Dosyalar/Proje/PGNViewer/app/src/main/res/drawable");
```

to a path locate in the device, example:

```
File folder = new File("/data/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer/");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will check and return... Regards – Aziz S. Kural

Comment: Do you have the permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Manifest file?

Comment: Very sorry I placed my answers in the wrong place. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in these lines:

```
File folder = new File("D:/Android_Dosyalar/Proje/PGNViewer/app/src/main/res/drawable");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

as listOfFiles, it seems, null.

If you want to get a list of all your drawables, you might want to try this:

```
Field[] drawables = chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer.R.drawable.class.getFields();

for (Field f : drawables) {
    try {
         System.out.println("R.drawable." + f.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will check and return... Regards

Comment: `folder` is not `null`. `listOfFiles` could be `null`, but not `folder`.

Comment: Hello, I think I put the comment to the wrong place or it was placed there later. I tried the above snippet of yours and this  what I get:
 
I just get a black screen. However I can see from the logcat that it is seeing the files.Can you make any sense of what went wrong??.....11-05 23:22:33.189 10517-10542/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 11-05 23:22:33.189 10517-10542/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb431b680, error=EGL_SUCCESS –

Comment: 25237-25237/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer I/System.out: R.drawable.snackbar_background 11-05 23:39:50.192 25237-25237/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer I/System.out: R.drawable.wb 11-05 23:39:50.192 25237-25237/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer I/System.out: R.drawable.wk 11-05 23:39:50.192 25237-25237/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer I/System.out: R.drawable.wn 11-05 23:39:50.192 25237-25237/chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer I/System.out: R.drawable.wp The files that it reads. If I remove the braces from the snippet it gives an empty screen with braces a dark screen

Comment: The black screen I guess depends on what else you have in your onCreate/onResume. The method itself works, as I checked it on several of my apps. Post your current code.

Comment: Hello, I got it working but gives only the last item. (It overwrites) The code:TextView mytextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Field[] drawables = chessactivepgnviewer.com.pgnviewer.R.drawable.class.getFields();

        for (Field f : drawables) {
            try {
                mytextview.setText("R.drawable." + f.getName()+" \n");
               
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

Comment: what do you want the result to be?

Comment: with Textview being: <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="20"
            android:text="Lastik Burada" />

Comment: I need to see the list. I tried different things but it did not work...??

Comment: I'm not sure a TextView is the best solution for such a list, but if you want to try you should concatenate the resuls using StringBuilder, and then set them all to textView outside the loop

Comment: I will try your solution. Consider this done with your code. Thank you for your patience. I am a (novice) in java android!

Answer (score 0):

The folder doesn't exists. So, folder.listFiles() return null.

If you put a picture inside the apk, use the assets folder for that.